# Why can't I make jQuery calls like $.whatever()?

Tags: jquery

A question in which I probably demonstrate how little I know about jQuery:

I was working up some jQuery (1.4.4) code today that (I thought) was just like some other code I've written before. In it, I called `$.ajax(arguments)`, which promptly produced the error

> Uncaught `TypeError`: Cannot call method `ajax` of `undefined`

When I changed the call to `jQuery.ajax(arguments)`, all was well.  Methods other than `.ajax()` were similarly affected.

What's up -- I thought the two notations were equivalent?  I'm obviously doing something wrong/stupid/ignorant, but I just don't see it.  Surely somebody out there can clear this up?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any other frameworks in the same project? It's possible other frameworks are using the `$` operator and causing a conflict. http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: Have you loaded the jQuery javascipt?

Comment: @Richard Seeing as `jQuery.ajax(...)` works, I'd say that's a given

Answer (score 5):

Are you using any other JS libraries? Prototype for instance?

The safest way to run jQuery code using the `$` shortcut is like this

```
jQuery(function($){
    // jQuery code here using $
});
```

This is equivalent to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // jQuery code here using $
});
```

**Edit:** For running code outside of the document ready context, see [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590595/why-cant-i-make-jquery-calls-like-whatever/5590622#5590622).

Answer (score 4):

It could be that '$' has been used by other code as a variable or function. Prototype library is using '$' as well.

Answer (score 4):

As well the other suggestions, you could wrap your code in a structure like this...

```
(function($) {

   // $ will point to jQuery here, guaranteed.

})(jQuery);
```

This function self invokes (defining an anonymous function and then calling it with `()`), where  `jQuery` becomes the first argument of the anonymous function, which is `$`. It's a handy trick.

Comment: It's also the recommended way to [write plugin code](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Getting_Started)

Comment: (function($) {

   // $ will point to jQuery here, guaranteed.

}(jQuery)); <- Note that subtle change in the parenthesis if you want to pass jsLint.com tests.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you have a conflict with the name $. This is often caused by using another library on the page that also makes use of the same character as a variable name. Try using the [jQuery noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).